# Check if Token belongs to a member of Admin group

Tags: .net, winapi

I have a code that should be able to tell if an application is running under an administrator user.

Right now, I can get the process's token and extract the SID of the owner of the process. Works well. So I have this "SecurityIdentifier" object, but I don't know how to check if it is indeed a member of admin group.

So if any one knows a way, that would be great.

However, now, I found a way to create a WindowsIdentity object from the token I retrieved from the process and it seems that it does the impersonating currently. But then, after calling the WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole method, I get a big "Access Denied" error from the Win32. So I actually hit an other dead end.

Any idea?

It is of no importance if the answer relies on WinAPI or .NetFramework.

Thanks

Comment: You may, for example, use System.DirectoryServices, go through all users until you find required one then check her groups

Comment: Can you tell us how you get the SID via Win32?  If this can be done in .Net you can call IsInRole

Comment: @AlexK. More info added.

Comment: You should be able to P/Invoke CheckTokenMembershipEx with the Administrators SID.  You'll need to convert the token to an impersonation token first via DuplicateToken, using the SecurityIdentification impersonation level.  (But there may be a .NET method that will do all this for you, I don't know.  )

Comment: @HarryJohnston, As a matter of fact "WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole" does exactly that. The only problem I found was this "Access Denied" thing happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after checking the source code of `WindowsIdentity` and `WindowsPrincipal` classes, I found that the reason for getting "**Access Denied**" was the way I retrieved the token in first place. 
Let's start from beginning:

`WindowsIdentity` is a class representing a process/thread token. So a way to initialize one is to provide a token. In my case I retrieved the token from another process using the `OpenProcessToken` function.

This works great for querying the token data and retrieving information. As in my case I did. But when used next to `WindowsPrincipal` class, it is not enough.

`WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole` use the `CheckTokenMembershipEx` to see if the token belongs to a user group. But to be able to use the `CheckTokenMembershipEx` function, you need to impersonate the process/thread token. `WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole` is completely aware of that and will create an impersonating token using the `DuplicateTokenEx` if the provided `WindowsIdentity` has the impersonating level of `None`.

Unfortunately tho, I made a mistake. When opening the process to get the token, I didn't expect this behavior. In-fact I didn't even know that `WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole` uses the `CheckTokenMembershipEx` function under the hood. So I didn't asked for `Duplicate` access when opening the process token. This resulted in `DuplicateTokenEx` to fail and showing of "**Access Denied**" message. Adding the right, solved everything.

Here is the code for anyone interested:

```
    public static WindowsIdentity GetProcessIdentity(Process process)
    {
        SafeTokenHandle token = SafeTokenHandle.InvalidHandle;
        try
        {
            if (!Methods.OpenProcessToken(process.Handle, TokenAccessLevels.Query | TokenAccessLevels.Duplicate, out token))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
            return new WindowsIdentity(token.DangerousGetHandle());
        }
        finally
        {
            token.Dispose();
        }
    }

   private static TokenElevationType GetTokenElevation(IntPtr token)
    {
        var elevationTypeLength = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (int));
        var elevationType = (TokenElevationType) 0;
        if (!Methods.GetTokenInformation(token,
            TokenInformationClass.TokenElevationType,
            ref elevationType, elevationTypeLength, out elevationTypeLength))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        return elevationType;
    }

    public static bool IsProcessElevated(Process process)
    {
        WindowsIdentity processIdentity = GetProcessIdentity(process);
        var tokenElevation = GetTokenElevation(processIdentity.Token);
        if (tokenElevation == TokenElevationType.Limited)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (tokenElevation == TokenElevationType.Full)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Do we have a Default elevation type? Then the process elevation status depends directly 
        // to the owner user being a member of the Administrative group.
        return new WindowsPrincipal(processIdentity).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
```